# Why is this post getting constantly downvoted, and will it prevent me from undoing my question ban?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [What YouTube API allows the reading of a livechat on a stream NOT OWNED by the bot owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023661/what-youtube-api-allows-the-reading-of-a-livechat-on-a-stream-not-owned-by-the-b)

This post is constantly gaining downvotes and receiving no positive attention, which is preventing me from undoing my question ban. I followed the question guides, and yet it still keeps getting downvoted. Can someone please explain? I'm worried the current -4 votes may make it impossible to undo my question ban.

Comment: Do you know how did you get the question ban in first place? You've asked only six questions till date as I can see from your profile. So I find it difficult to digest that someone can face question ban just after 6 questions.

Comment: @RBT: deleted questions count towards the ban. You can’t see OP’s question history.

Comment: Your edited question is off topic: “What API would allow me to do this?” There is a specific mention of this type of question in the help pages about what is on-topic.

Comment: @RBT i have not not left any questions on Stack Overflow specifically as deleted. So I don't know how I got the question ban. Despite now having 27 reputation, and 3 upvotes on this meta post, I still have my question ban.

Comment: Your question shows quite clearly that you have no idea what type questions are allowed here.  So a question ban seems to be quite appropriate.

Comment: Now since I've the full context I can make two suggestions - 1. Delete the referred SO question as you also know by now that it is off topic. This will result in reputation reversal of the points you lost due to down-votes. 2. Wait patiently for a cool down period. Keep posting good answers. I'm sure SO will lift up your question ban on its own after a cool down period. I doubt you can do much about the question ban as an end user of the website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two simple things to unpack on this one.

1. Your question is not suitable for the site because it's asking a question that is too broad.  Both incarnations were.
2. Had you perused [what questions were on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, you'd see that your question falls out of that scope fairly succinctly.

   > Questions asking for support for offsite resources such as App Stores are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Direct your questions to the relevant organisation instead.

   I would view asking about what third-party API can fulfill your requirements as something analogous to asking for support for an offsite resource.  We can't be YouTube's documentation; that is better suited to get an answer to your question as opposed to us.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would this still prevent be from being able to earn my question privilages back?

Comment: Likely, yes...the idea is that you have to demonstrate that you're asking quality questions.  Anything less than that would stand to harm your chances at getting out of a q-ban.